# how to run function from frame

Tags: javascript, html, frame, frameset, siebel

I have one file (CCPageContainer.swt) that contain number of frames, and each frame call file.
(swt - siebel template file)

this is part of the code with a specific frame:

```
<HTML dir="swe:dir">
<head>
<title><swe:this property="Title"/></title>
<swe:include file="CCStylesChoice.swt"/>
</head>

<swe:switch>
    <swe:frameset htmlAttr="rows='30,30,27,18,42,*,15' border='0' frameborder='No'">
       <swe:frame htmlAttr="marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' noresize scrolling='No'">
             <swe:include file="CCFrameGoToView.swt"/>      
       </swe:frame> 
    </swe:frameset>
</swe:switch>
</HTML>
```

in the CCFrameGoToView.swt file that has been called I'm trying to call to alert function:

```
 <HTML dir="swe:dir">

    <body>
    <script language="JScript">
    function alert_test()
    {
        try
        {
            alert("test");
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            //document.write("oops.. an error has occurred");
        }
    }

 </script>
    <form name="myForm">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ALERT: <input type="Button" value="alert5" onClick="alert_test();"><br></td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
    </form>
<swe:scripts/>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that the alert message doesn't work when I'm pushing the button.

If I’m running only CCFrameGoToView.swt the alert button is working, and i see the message after i push.
but when I'm trying to run it from CCPageContainer.swt, nothing happened when i'm pushing the alert button.

I've also tried window.parent, window.top etc.

please your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try hanging your custom function off the top window so the click handler will be able to find its way to it:

```
top.alert_test = function alert_test()
{
   // blah blah blah
}
```

then:

```
onClick="top.alert_test();"
```

As an aside, it feels strange to be directly injecting code into a Siebel Web Template file, so maybe if you tell us a little more about what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to help you think about a better way to accomplish it.